# find a comma deliminted string element and remove the line

Tags: string

I have the follow text file and wish to remove all lines where the time (4th element) is not a 15 min. interval. Below is a file example:

`224,2012,325,2029,1,0,0,0,0.458,8
224,2012,325,2030,1,0,0,0,0.458,9
224,2012,325,2031,1,0,0,0,0.458,9
224,2012,325,2032,1,0,0,0,0.458,9
224,2012,325,2033,1,0,0,0,0.459,8
224,2012,325,2034,1,0,0,0,0.458,8
224,2012,325,2035,1,0,0,0,0.458,8
224,2012,325,2036,1,0,0,0,0.459,8
224,2012,325,2037,1,0,0,0,0.459,9
224,2012,325,2038,1,0,0,0,0.459,8
224,2012,325,2039,1,0,0,0,0.458,9
224,2012,325,2040,1,0,0,0,0.458,9
224,2012,325,2041,1,0,0,0,0.459,9
224,2012,325,2042,1,0,0,0,0.459,9
224,2012,325,2043,1,0,0,0,0.459,9
224,2012,325,2044,1,0,0,0,0.459,8
224,2012,325,2045,1,0,0,0,0.459,8
224,2012,325,2046,1,0,0,0,0.457,8`

With the non-fifteen min. intervals removed the corrected file should be:

`224,2012,325,2030,1,0,0,0,0.458,9
224,2012,325,2045,1,0,0,0,0.459,8`

Comment: What language would you like this done in? It's relatively simple in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since you havne't provided me a language, I'm going to give you the logic to do it in Java to help you out. Java isn't a scripting language, but whatever, it can't hurt:

Assume `s` is a String that has the value of one row of data.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(s.split(",")[3].substring(2)) % 15 == 0) {
    //You have a row that satisfies your condition
}
```

You can do whatever you like if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: I'm assuming the value is a time in `HHmm` format, so rather than doing a modulus, you'd have to compare the last two digits with `15`, `30`, `45`, or `00`.

Answer (score 0):

Schoolbook example:

```
awk -F, '!$4%15' filename
```